# How to setup OMISE PHP SDK to Laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel, omise

I'm starting to learn [Omise](https://www.omise.co) Payment Getway. On Omise [documentation](https://www.omise.co/integrations) have information about [PHP SDK](https://github.com/omise/omise-php). I'm using Laravel Framework on it. However, i'm struggling to implement the Omise PHP SDK into my Laravel site..

I have 2 question when setup the Omise PHP SDK :

1. The integration - after i install Omise by composer. i don't know how to use it. first, i want to display my Omise balance. here is my code on controller

```
use Omise\OmiseBalance;


class OmiseController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $balance = OmiseBalance::retrieve();
        dd($balance);
    }
}
```

but display error

```
Class "Omise\OmiseBalance" not found
```

i tried other way, but still not work..

2. Place the Secret and Public Key - where should i put the Secret key and Public Key on my Laravel. and how to fetch the keys?
   Currently i just put this keys into my file `.env`

```
OMISE_PUBLIC_KEY=pkey_test_xxx
OMISE_SECRET_KEY=skey_test_xxx
OMISE_API_VERSION=2019-05-29
```

What is the correct way for me to integrate Omise PHP SDK into my Laravel Site. please help.

Comment: Class XXX not found can have multiple reasons: Either the class name is wrong (e.g. a typo, check first) or otherwise autoload configuration went bonkers. As you wrote you installed with composer, those packages normally come preconfigured for autoloading with composer, so *should* not be the issue but autoload configuration can have multiple ends where things can break (file-system configuration, PHP runtime configuration, the PHP application configuration) so with such little information this is hard to say. I'd try to get rid of the class not found error first. Limit the question to it.